# Send emails to clients email address (without storing their password in settings.py)

Tags: django

I'm wanting to use `send_mail()` to have messages from the contact form send to my clients email address. I think what I'm missing is the "email backend" in my settings.py, which I don't really understand how to use properly..

Here's my settings.py:

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: not getting your point of 'without storing password'

Comment: @uglyCoder The way I have seen is to have an email in password in your settings.py which is used to send the emails.

Comment: Also, this will hel you in and out https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/13/how-to-send-email.html

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need to store a password, or anything 'secretive' in your settings.py. You store them as env variables and access them in your code. Secondly, you will be using SMTP to send emails. Depending on the service you use, you would need to store a key / password (again as an env variable).